# How can i use the variables and the columns in one dataset at same time in SSRS?

Tags: variables, reporting-services

I have a table with two columns: X and Y, and I have a stored procedure for the calculation.

If i want to make a report in SSRS, in the dataset are only the variables, without columns. I need the columns too.

How can i use the variables and the columns in one dataset at same time?

Here is the code:

```
create procedure Reg
as
Declare @sumx float;
Declare @sumy float;
Declare @XY float;

select 
     @sumx= Sum(X)
    ,@sumy= Sum(y)
    ,@XY= Sum(y) * Sum(X)
from stat;

select
     stat=@sumx
    ,XY=@XY

select 
     X=X
    ,Y=Y
from stat

go
```

Here are the variables and the columns.

SQL Managment Studio results:

[image]

Here are only the variables without columns name:

[image]

I want use the columns and the variables in SSRS at same time.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a second dataset.

SSRS datasets return only the first dataset in the query.  Your query currently has two, as evidenced by the output of two datasets in Management Studio.

The first dataset will need to return `stat` and `XY` and the second return `X` and `Y`

So, Dataset 1 would be:

```
select 
     Sum(X) as stat
    ,Sum(y) * Sum(X) as XY
from stat;
```

and Dataset 2 would be:

```
select 
     X
    ,Y
from stat
```

Comment: I've tried this. Therefore i need the columns and the variables are in one dataset, becasue i want to make a  parameter field  as filter. If i select  from X values, not change the stat's or XY's value.

Comment: @Ztrew  What you are after is completely impossible.  You can't return two datasets from the same query.  You ***need*** to have two datasets.

Comment: @Ztrew  I have just realised that you don't actually need a large chunk of your code.  I have updated the queries accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dave!

If i want to filter my values, need to create two parameter fields? With one parameter field can not filter the two datasets...

Comment: This should not be posted as an answer.  But yes, one SSRS parameter can be referenced in multiple dataset scripts.